# JSON Object to Array Javascript Lodash parsing

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, lodash

I have following JSON

```
  {
    SYS1_DATA: "s-1,s2,s3,\ns-4,s-5,s-6,s-7",
    SYS2_DATA: "s1,s2,s3,\ns4,s5,s6,s7",
    COMPARE: [
      {
        cell_no: 2,
        line_no: 0
      },
      {
        cell_no: 3,
        line_no: 1
      },
      {
        cell_no: 4,
        line_no: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    SYS1_DATA: "cs-1,cs2,cs3,\ncs-4,cs-5,cs-6,cs-7",
    SYS2_DATA: "cs1,cs2,cs3,\ncs4,cs5,cs6,cs7",
    COMPARE: [
      {
        cell_no: 2,
        line_no: 1
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

here my requirement is to parse this object and HIGHLIGHT specific cells back to UI from compare reference. (this is similar like DIFF feature but more customized to specific requirement)

USE case is  - Syn1data and Sync2data both I need to compare and there is a possible list of them (as shared in JSON), 
case 1: Parse all data covert syn1data and sync2data to the array and highlight the specific cell with cell no and from line no (pick this info from Compare array). 
case 2: expected output will be like this example

```
SYS1_DATA: "s-1,s2,s3,\n<span class='error'>s-4</span>,s-5,s-6,s-7",
SYS2_DATA: "s1,s2,s3,\n<span class='error'>s4</span>,s5,s6,s7",
```

to show different in cell values.
here is my inprocess codexandbox link -> https://codesandbox.io/s/logic-1-6bkgs?file=/src/index.js

is there any library I can use here for this purpose? 
Thanks

Comment: You have code. What is the exact problem?

Comment: What is the rule for the span? you have s-1 vs s1. s-4 vs s4, s-5 vs s5 etc

Answer (score 1):

This was non-trivial

```js
const data = [{ SYS1_DATA: "s-1,s2,s3,\ns-4,s-5,s-6,s-7", SYS2_DATA: "s1,s2,s3,\ns4,s5,s6,s7", COMPARE: [{ cell_no: 2, line_no: 0 }, { cell_no: 3, line_no: 1 }, { cell_no: 4, line_no: 1 } ] }, { SYS1_DATA: "cs-1,cs2,cs3,\ncs-4,cs-5,cs-6,cs-7", SYS2_DATA: "cs1,cs2,cs3,\ncs4,cs5,cs6,cs7", COMPARE: [{ cell_no: 2, line_no: 0 }] } ]; 

const processLines = (sys, compare) =>
  sys.split("\n")
  .map((line, i) => line
    .split(",")
    .map(
      (cell, j) => compare.find(o => o.line_no === i && o.cell_no === j) ?
        `<span>${cell}</span>` : cell
    )
  );

const process = (sys1, sys2, compare) => {
  sys1 = processLines(sys1, compare)//.flat();
  sys2 = processLines(sys2, compare)//.flat();
  return {
    sys1: sys1,
    sys2: sys2
  }

};

const res = data.map(item => process(item.SYS1_DATA, item.SYS2_DATA, item.COMPARE))


console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, only problem with this I have compare array, where I am getting which cell and which line to highlight.

Comment: Ok, fixed the compare